VSCode "Remote Window" does not load my profile the same as a normal ssh connection
When I am connecting to a Linux server using Visual Studio Code Remote Window, and open a terminal, My profile gets not loaded the same, as it would connecting via a normal SSH command.
There are multiple functions, that are not working the same, as the system I'm using has a lot of login scripts. But to keep it simple, one example is, that I don't see the MOTD, when opening a terminal.
What is the difference, between logging in to a server via SSH on a normal local console, and opening a terminal once I am connected to that server via Remote Window?
